# Can't pickle generator objects

Tags: python, iterator, multiprocessing, generator

I have following working code

```
import multiprocessing as mp
import time
import datetime

def yielder(IMapIterator):
    while True:
        try:
            yield IMapIterator.next()
        except:
            return

def download_one(x):
    time.sleep(1)
    return x + '_/'

def test_one(x):
    time.sleep(0.3)
    return x + '\\'

pool_download = mp.Pool(2)
iterator_download = pool_download.imap(download_one, ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'])
generator_download = yielder(iterator_download)

pool_test = mp.Pool(2)
iterator_test = pool_test.imap(test_one, generator_download)
generator_test = yielder(iterator_test)

for i in range(20):
    print(str(datetime.datetime.utcnow()), generator_test.next())
    time.sleep(0.5)
```

Where `generator_download` is generator.
Also have the following *non-working code* with error from title where `generator_download` is also a generator:

```
import multiprocessing as mp

def yielder(queue):
    while True:
        element = queue.get()
        if element is None:
            break
        else:
            yield element

manager = mp.Manager()
queue_download = manager.Queue()
pool_downloader = manager.Pool(2)
list_urls = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']

def downloader(url):
    time.sleep(np.random.random())
    return a + '_'

generator_download = yielder(queue_download)
r = pool_downloader.imap(downloader, generator_download)
```

Can someone explain difference?
Globally I want to have 3 queues and 2 pools which consistently and continuously download and testing some objects, until last queue is  empty.

Comment: Your second example doesn't seem complete. There is only one pool and your managed queue has no items on it.

Comment: Also: `yield IMapIterator.next()` doesn't look right. Don't you mean: `yield IMapIterator.__next__()`

Comment: shortened the second example for clarity. next() and __next__() gives absolutely same result

Comment: **No!**: *AttributeError: 'generator' object has no attribute 'next'*. And with regards to shortening your second example for "clarity", it doesn't accomplish that. And if I want to try to run it, I have to try to assemble something by pulling in code from your first example. I might be lazier than you, but the difference is I am not looking for a resolution to this question and I have now moved on. See [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

solved with replacement

```
pool_downloader = manager.Pool(2)
```

to

```
pool_downloader = mp.Pool(2)
```

I'm not sure if I understood correctly, but it seems that the manager's copy was trying to transfer himself to himself, what caused the error